# What are the potential consequences of "gifting" a higher-level spell slot to a PC?

Tags: dnd-5e

(edited to walk-back the strength of the bonus)

Some brief background:

I'm planning an adventure where, at the end, I would like to offer my players (all 3rd level) a choice. They can either claim the MacGuffin, and go through the arduous task of dragging it back to town so they can cure the king for a small reward, or our Knowledge Domain Cleric can consume it to gain its powers. The idea is that the players can choose between the "moral" but lengthy and difficult option, or the easier self-beneficial option.

Knowing my players, they'll probably choose the first, but I'd like to make the self-beneficial option powerful enough to be tempting, without being necessarily game-breaking. My idea is to offer the Cleric a free 3rd or 4th-level spell slot to cast from with every long rest, with the intention to allow them to cast 3rd and 4th-level spells, not just upcast.

These players are all relatively inexperienced (maybe a dozen games each), so I don't think they'd intentionally try to break the game with this extra boost, but I'm not sure if it would be too overpowered for such an early stage of play. I'm also concerned that offering only one player a boost would leave the others feeling left-out.

What could be the potential downsides of offering players this bonus so early on?

Comment: To be clear, it is just the spell slot on offer not any 4th or 5th level spells so it only lets them upcast a level 1 or 2 spell?

Comment: @Steve iirc, Clerics are able to prepare any spell in the cleric spell list, so long as they have the slots to cast it, right? my idea was indeed to let them be able to cast 4th or 5th level spells (edited the question for clarity)

Comment: "The spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots." Very true. I forgot that. You are correct, They could then have a 4th or 5th level spell available

Comment: Suggestion: Make it give them a specific spell or spells - from a different list. This way you can choose something tempting, but that doesn't alter the game away from what might be expected of characters of that level. Additionally, this is something they could never get normally, even with patience, unless they do this thing.

Comment: Is there a clear reason that you are not offering a wand or a spell scroll as a reward / boon?  Or a ring or spell storing.  Perhaps you can explain why none of those meet your needs/criteria.

Comment: Why only the cleric? Don't the others get anything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Potentially a broken game

Before introducing a new thing, it’s worthwhile looking at what things are in the game that are like your new thing. Here is a list of magic items that grant additional spell slots:

> 

Now, there are things that *regain* spell slots like the Wizard’s *Arcane Recovery* and the [Pearl of Power](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/pearl-of-power). But they are limited to half the Wizard’s level (maximum 6th level slots) at the cost of a short rest or 3rd level at the cost of an action respectively.

What you are proposing is *way* more powerful than anything that exists in the game.

Plus, you are proposing to make it work like an Epic Boon - something PC’s *might* get *after* 20th level.

As to the specific idea:

- spell slots are **the** most valuable resource spellcasters have
- clerics are **the** most versatile and (arguably) powerful spellcasters in the game
- 5th level spells are the second most useful spells in the game (behind 3rd level). Think about how spells like *Commune*, *Flame Strike*, *Legend Lore*, *Mass Cure Wounds* and *Scrying* will impact 3rd level gameplay. 4th level cleric spells are not *as* good although *Banishment* and *Locate Creature* can alter the course of an encounter or adventure.
- There is no (mechanical) cost to this; not even an attunement slot.

Think again.

Answer (score 5):

## It just changes the game but doesn't break it

Consider what the player will do with such a boon.  You are giving the player a free spell at third level that they would have needed to wait until 7th.  So what are they going to do with it?

I'll just use three examples.

1. Upcast Spiritual Weapon to 4th level.  Now it does 2d8 + Wisdom, pretty much the most powerful attack the party can make at third level.
2. Cast Revivify.  Revivify is a must-have for a party and now they get it two levels early.  They can be a little more aggressive about battle, but it likely isn't all that different.  It does let them continue fighting instead of stopping to stabilize.
3. Cast Banishment.  This is a super powerful spell, and likely the first thing they will use on any BBEG, 4 levels before it would've been an option.

So now, what does that do to the campaign?  It might be significant, it might be only a little.  Eventually 1 extra 4th level spell is nice, but by 9th level it's hardly noticeable.  You just need to decide how important it is, and what you want to give the characters to start their moral quandary.  I would expect a chaotic character to use it for themselves.

Comment: Nice examples, I could definitely see Banishment presenting itself as an issue...